# Powershell script not executing past for loop

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, each

I have made some progress, and stuck with the attachment. Below script now sends an email but with not an attachment

```
$sub = "APERAK/INVRPT Report "
$to="Chandan.Talasila@XXXXXXXX.com"
$folder = "C:\script\APERAK"
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\script\APERAK"
$tstmp = Get-Date -UFormat "%H%M"
$dstamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d"
$from="Reports@XXXXXXXX.com"
$smtpserver = "mail.XXXXXXXX.com"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {

$subject=  $sub + $dstamp #+ " " +$tstmp
$filename =  $files[$i].FullName
$abpath = $folder + $files[$i].FullName

$attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($abpath)

$body= Get-Content $filename
$SMTP = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
$MSG = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $body)
$MSG.attachments.add($attachment)
$SMTP.send($msg)
}
```

Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item"
At C:\GentranScripts\APERAK_REPORT_EMAIL1.ps1:22 char:21
+ $MSG.attachments.add <<<< ($attachment)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: `for some reason, the script is entering into the for loop.` ... so what is the problem here ?

Comment: do you mean is NOT entering? or is entering but not sending the email? more details, please?

Comment: I dont know what the problem is, the cursor is not entering the for loop.

Comment: I guess its having trouble with getting array count from $files.Count..this script executes well on my desktop, when I move it to the server...it does nothing.

Comment: Are you sure "C:\Reports\APERAK" is the correct path on your server? Try to output `$files.Count` on its own and look at the output.

Comment: PS C:\GentranScripts> $files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK"
PS C:\GentranScripts> echo $files.Count
PS C:\GentranScripts> echo $files


    Directory: C:\Reports\APERAK


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        12/16/2018  10:05 PM       1065 18110963_0.ATM20181211114626187-8923.csv

Comment: Why don't you use foreach? As I can see you do not use $i for anything beyond addressing of an array's element.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Get-Childitem` will return two types of objects. If there's just a single file, `$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK"` will contain a `FileInfo`. If there's more, it'll contain an array of FileInfo objects. Let's look at a sample case:

```
md foo
cd foo
set-content -Path "foo.txt" -Value ""
$files = gci
$files.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo

set-content -Path "foo2.txt" -Value ""
$files2 = gci
$files2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

As for a solution, wrap `gci` results into an array. Like so,

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK")
```

Comment: @chandanT `Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK"` can also return `DirectoryInfo` objects. These are subfolders. In your loop you expect everything to be a file on which you can do an `Get-Content`. To make sure you only get `FileInfo` objects, use `Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK" -File` or use `Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\APERAK" | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` if you are on an older PowerShell version

Comment: Please note that a scalar (single) return object is only a problem in PowerShell _v2_. In v3+, even single objects have a `.Count` property (try `'foo'.Count`, for instance)

Comment: I have made some progress, and stuck with the attachment.